# Validation Based Upon Associated Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, bdd

I have two models: User and Lesson. I only want lessons to be assigned to users that are admins.

What is the best way to ensure this? I am currently attempting to create a custom validator like so:

```
class BelongsToAdminValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator  
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)  
    unless value.admin?
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must belong to an admin")  
    end  
  end  
end
```

But this leads to Rspec saying:

```
undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
```

Which makes sense.

Is a custom validator the best way to do this? Or should I be checking if the to-be-assigned user is an admin in a controller?

Comment: Is `admin?` a method defined in `User`? Maybe that should be `unless object.admin?`?

Comment: It's a boolean which automatically gets the "?" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the easiest way of doing it is:

```
# Lesson model
validate :allow_only_admins

private
def allow_only_admins
  errors.add(:user, "must be admin user!") if (user.blank? || !user.admin?)
end
```

I assumed that you have association named `user` and that your user object responds to `admin?` method.

Comment: Perfect. Much simpler than my approach. Thank you!